# Unable to compile RXTX with Yocto, javac missing

Tags: java, yocto, rxtx

When I try to add the RXtX library to my recipe, Bitbake give me this error:

```
"/bin/bash: /yocto/build_raspberry/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/jamvm-native/2.0.0-devel+gitAUTOINC+6cef41d859-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/javac: No such file or directory"
```

If I check the contents of the folder, there is a "javac.jikes" but not "java"

I try to replace "jamvm-native" with "cacao-native", the same error happen but in "cacao" folder.

If a remove RXTX from the recipe, everything compile OK

My local.conf contains:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-initial-native = "cacao-initial-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-native = "jamvm-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/javac-native = "ecj-bootstrap-native"
PREFERRED_RPROVIDER_java2-runtime = "openjdk-8"
```

My recipe contains:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openjdk-8 rxtx "
```

I also try the "openjdk-8-test-image" recipe and adding "RXTX", but I get the same result.

And I try to compile "Cacao" and "Jamvm", they both won't compile. For "cacao" I get: `# warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
|    ^~~~~~~
| md-os.cpp:41:22: error: field 'uc_mcontext' has incomplete type 'sigcontext'
|     struct sigcontext uc_mcontext;
|                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
| md-os.cpp:41:11: note: forward declaration of 'struct sigcontext'
|     struct sigcontext uc_mcontext;
|            ^~~~~~~~~~
| Makefile:420: recipe for target 'md-os.lo' failed`

For Jamvm I get :

```
 /bin/bash: /yocto/build_raspberry/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/jamvm/2.0.0-devel+gitAUTOINC+6cef41d859-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/ecj-initial: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you need javac in a recipe, that recipe must add java to dependancies with something like `DEPENDS += "virtual/javac-native"`.

Comment: Thank for your response. But I check the rxtx recipe already had the "virtual/javac-native" dependancies.